# From VS Code Extension API open file in markdown preview

Tags: vscode-extensions

So I want to open a file in markdown preview, so when the certain command is triggered I want to open a file in vscode (but in markdown preview mode)

*What have I tried so far:*

- This will open the file in raw text mode

```js
const docs = await workspace.openTextDocument("/path/to/file.md");
await window.showTextDocument(docs);
```

- This will trigger markdown command and the just opened file from above will be rendered in markdown preview

```js
await commands.executeCommand("markdown.showPreview");
```

Is there a better way to achieve this, since it take fraction of seconds to open the file and then trigger markdown preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markdown `markdown.showPreview` command takes a uri as its first argument. For example:

```
const uri = vscode.URI.file("/path/to/file.md");
await commands.executeCommand("markdown.showPreview", uri);
```

To control the column the editor is opened in, use the `markdown.showPreviewToSide` command instead. [Here are the arguments it takes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/7ee9aa4757212dd513e7cf4b9b67426401e64695/extensions/markdown-language-features/src/commands/showPreview.ts#L79)

Comment: works perfect, exactly what I was looking for. One tiny fix here though, it should be `vscode.Uri.file`, not URI

Comment: Note: `uri` must be `import { Uri } from "vscode";` and not `import { URI } from "vscode-uri"`. (might be subject to change depending on how you resolve externals)