# Open Markdown URL in preview via VSCode API

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I know that it is possible to programatically open a Markdown file in preview via `markdown.showPreview` by passing a URI to the command. However, passing a URI that is not a `file://` scheme, but is `http`, does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

### MWE

```js
  const url =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/fortran-lang/vscode-fortran-support/v3.3.0.md';
  const uri = vscode.Uri.parse(url, true);
  vscode.commands.executeCommand('markdown.showPreview', uri);
```

Related (but for local files): [From VS Code Extension API open file in markdown preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960216/from-vs-code-extension-api-open-file-in-markdown-preview)

Comment: You missed the actual source code that determines the behavior, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.67.2/extensions/markdown-language-features/src/commands/showPreview.ts#L17 Get started from there and you can find why remote URLs are not supported.

Comment: I don't think this do-it-yourself comment is a particularly constructive in this case. If you know why this is happening feel free to post an answer. Inviting some to go read and understand the vscode source code and particularly what goes on in ` createNewDynamicPreview` is an obvious and unhelpful suggestion.

Comment: People are free to leave comments/answers, not necessarily "constructive".